# Magento Banner Slider Not Loading All Images- Need to Flush Cache?

Tags: magento, caching, magento2, banner

I updated my website's banner slider in Magento 2 today. I replaced existing images (fully working banner/slider) with lower-res images of the same dimensions. Now, only the first image is loading, and it is not sliding thru all of the images, nor showing arrows or pagination.

I have read to flush my cache. I am worried to do that because I do not have direct access to the code/files/server that my site is hosted on if something were to bug when I flush it. Is that a reasonable worry, or should I go ahead and flush it regardless? Flush the entire cache or just a specific cache type?

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the entire cache it will affect the loading speed of your website. So instead of clearing the entire cache, you should clear the specific cache you want.